# How to quickly browse through floppy image files

Tags: disk-image

I know how to mоunt a floppy image, but I want to quickly browse trough many images in a rapid fashion.

In Windows (with a Total Commander plugin) I can browse through archives as if they were directories. And images (of single partitions) are treated as archives. I can enter an archive, see the contents, go up, arrow down to the next archive and repeat. This way I can reach speeds of up to 1-2 floppy images per second.

How can I do the same in Ubuntu (in Gnome or whatever) (without fully emulating everything in Wine)?

Comment: Have you tried Midnight Commander yet?

Comment: I'd love to hear how to configure mc to open FAT12 images, i.e. by answering https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127146/midnight-commander-rules-for-accessing-archives-through-vfs